# How to resolve duplication in Slick queries with multiple joins, join types, criteria

Tags: scala, slick, dry

I have a bunch of different queries that fetch the same data, but by applying different criteria.

At the moment, I am duplicating the entire codebase from Query to DBIOAction because I can't see how to make these composable. Here's one example of the duplicate queries.

(I have simplified the example a little, the actual code joins over thirteen tables):

```
  override val createAction = {

    val join = master
      .join(child1.filter(child1Filter)).on(_.id === _.id)  /* DRY1 */
      .joinLeft(child2).on(_._1.id === _.id)
      .joinLeft(child3).on(_._1._1.id === _.id)
      .joinLeft(child4).on(_._1._1._1.id === _.id)
      .joinLeft(child5).on(_._1._1._1._1.id === _.id)
      .joinLeft(child6).on(_._1._1._1._1._1.id === _.id)

    val query = for {
      ((((((r, c1), c2), c3), c4), c5), c6) <- join
    } yield (r.id, c1.value, c2.value, c3.value, c4.value, c5.value, c6.value)  /* DRY2 */

    query.result.map( tuples =>
        tuples.groupBy(_._1)
          .map {
          case(id, tuples) => {
            val c1 = tuples.map(_._2).distinct.head /* DRY3 */
            val c2 = tuples.map(_._3).distinct.head
            val c3 = tuples.flatMap(_._4).distinct.headOption
            val c4 = tuples.flatMap(_._5).distinct.headOption
            val c5 = tuples.flatMap(_._6).distinct.headOption
            val c6 = tuples.flatMap(_._7).distinct.headOption

            SomeCaseClass(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6)
          }
      }
    )
  }
```

I have marked the three parts where just one change in the filter criteria changes the code:

`DRY1` - on any one join condition, we may choose to `joinLeft` or simply `join`. This has ramifications, because the resulting `join` has a different parameterised type. We may also want to add additional criteria.

`DRY2` - The type of `c1` depends on the type of the join made previously.

`DRY3` - Again, the join type affects how the results are mapped and the case class created.

So as an example, one query changes the join on `child1`, another changes it on `child2`.

I'm lacking some examples of more complicated queries that are composable and don't violate DRY.